# Entity Framework & WPF Datagrid binding

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, entity-framework-5

I have a pretty simple little app that is using EF and WPF. I'm trying to create a very lightweight 'project tracker' for our small team at work. The classes look like:

```cs
class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<ProjectNote> ProjectNotes { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string ProjectLead { get; set; }
}

class ProjectNote
{


    public int ProjectNoteId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEdited { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string LastEditedBy { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

}
```

I want to be able to display the following fields in a datagrid:

1. Project.Name
2. Project.Description
3. (Most Recent)ProjectNote.Detail

Basically, I want to have a Datagrid that allows my user to see the most recent notes for a Project and edit them if need be.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to structure my code (I'm using Code First/POCO) to allow the user to create a new ProjectNote from the Datagrid view. I don't know if I need another property of my Project class to allow for a single ProjectNote, or if I can code this (through a ViewModel) to properly instantiate a new ProjectNote when the user is editing a Datagrid that contains the Project data.

How can I create a datagrid that allows editing/creation across multiple entities?

Comment: You should have a `ProjectNote` property on your View Model, called something like `NewNote` and then structure your data grid to include the details required for that new property so the user can enter them.

Comment: If I do that though, how can I make sure (or where should I put the code anyway) that I am getting the most recent note for that Project in that property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a ViewModel, perhaps ProjectNoteViewModel, which contains the Note as well as the Project.  Then, you bind your collection/list of ProjectNoteViewModels to the `DataGrid`.

Alternatively, you could add a Project navigation property to the ProjectNote class, which would allow you to include the Project.Name and Project.Description in the `DataGridRow` for the ProjectNote.  If there is little or no business logic/complexity to this relationship, then this approach will work, but if there is any complexity or business rules you need to enforce, I'd recommend using a ViewModel.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42548/MVVM-and-the-WPF-DataGrid) provides a good walk through of using the `DataGrid` and MVVM together.  Basically, if you have DataBound the `DataGrid` to a list of some sort, the `DataGrid` will automatically create a new instance of your object for you and insert it into the collection when the user clicks the empty row at the bottom of the grid.

Comment: It is amazing that after searching for three days and reading A LOT of posts I didn't find that link. Thank you for the advice! I should be able to get this to work now.

Comment: I hear you, sometimes it's like finding the needle in a haystack!  Good luck.